# Why does "date" in Portuguese became "data", while in Dutch "datum" is used?

Tags: latin, romance-languages, dutch

I didn't study Latin, but I can recognize when a noun is singular or plural.

It's weird that *date* is used in the singular form *data* in Portuguese - a Neo-Latin language - while Dutch contains the form I'd say makes more sense, *datum*.

Comment: When I wrote that data is used in the plural form in Portuguese, I meant relative to Latin. In Portuguese data is actually the singular form, having feminine gender, so `a data`. The plural form is `as datas`. So actually having datum in Portuguese would be an exception in the language.

Comment: Russian also uses "data" for date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Italian, Spanish, Portuguese (etc.) data, and French date (whence English date) are all taken from Mediaeval Latin data, the plural of classical Latin datum, but reinterpreted in these languages as a singular noun. German and Dutch use the classical singular form datum.

All of these are bookish borrowings from Mediaeval or Classical Latin (so-called cultisms) and not organic descendants of the Latin words.

Comment: @ fdb A quick question. With the Romance languages, how do you know when it's a borrowed word from Classical Latin or an "organic descendant"? Could you please expand your answer and show what phonetic changes *should have happened* (but did not!) to Latin data to suggest a regular development?

Comment: @AlexB. In that case one would expect *dada in Spanish, Portugeuse and Italian.

Comment: Are you sure it would be dada in (standard) Italian as well? I don't think t turned into d there. In Spanish, dada is indeed the feminine past participle of dar.

Comment: @dainichi. The treatment of intervocalic -t- in Italian is complicated. You have amata, but also strada (from Latin strata).

Comment: @fdb, ah, good point, thanks for making me aware. So, in this particular case, would it depend on whether it's still regarded as a participle or reanalyzed as a noun? Or does it depend on something else?

Comment: Well, it any case, it's neuter/masculine plural, so it would be *dati* in Italian, and *dados* in Spanish and Portuguese.  (And *dato*/*dati* does exist in Italian.  I think the -d- in *strada* only evolved because it is very old and has lost the connection to *sternere*.)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably no straight answer, why this happened in two languages. Here's just one hypothesis that may give a good start.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=date) of *"date"* in English (and, likely, in other European languages) is:

> The Roman convention of closing every article of correspondence by writing "given" and the day and month -- meaning perhaps **"given to messenger"** -- led to data becoming a term for "the time (and place) stated."
>   A Roman letter would include something along the lines of *datum Romae pridie Kalendas Maias* -- "given at Rome on the last day of April."

As we see, the assumed full sentence is something like:

> *"This message **is given** on [day, month, year, and place]."*

"The message" is singular, hence, *"datum"*.

It is easy to suppose that "this message" may at some languages/areas change its meaning slightly: *"these statements **are given**…"* or *"these scripts **are given**…"*, both plural, hence, *"data"*.

Since the difference is very slight, it can be supposed that singular/plural variants may cycle, even in the same areas.

Comment: The day before the Kalends of May (pridie Kal. Maias) is indeed the last day of April.